# how to capture closing of a browser tab

Tags: javascript

We would like to throw a specific message before a user closes the browser. Is there a mechanism which will work across all major browsers (like IE, firefox, chrome, opera)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check [`onbeforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload):

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
  var e = e || window.event;

  if (has_message_to_throw) {

    // For IE and Firefox
    if (e) {
      e.returnValue = 'Specific message';
    }

    // For Safari
    return 'Specific message';

  }


};
```

Comment: I tried the following function, but it doesn't work for IE 8, latest version of Opera. What am I missing here?

window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
  var message = "Your confirmation message goes here.",
  e = e || window.event;
  // For IE and Firefox
  if (e) {
    e.returnValue = message;
  }

  // For Safari
  return message;
};

Comment: @Samuel: Looks like Opera doesn't support `onbeforeunload` (Ref: http://www.zachleat.com/web/2008/04/22/dont-let-the-door-hit-you-onunload-and-onbeforeunload/).

Answer (score 0):

From [Firefox Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/beforeunload?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/Mozilla_event_reference/beforeunload)

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
  var confirmationMessage = "\o/";

  (e || window.event).returnValue = confirmationMessage;     //Gecko + IE
  return confirmationMessage;                                //Webkit, Safari, Chrome etc.
});
```